# How do I draw toon-like black edges using shaders on iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm developing a simple 3D game using OpenGL ES 2.0 on iPhone. I need to draw black edges for my meshes, just like you'd see with toon shading, but without the other toon-like rendering effects.

How could I write vertex and fragment shaders to accomplish this kind of a look in an OpenGL ES 2.0 iOS app?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I want code that does X" questions are not appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 2):

yes, the cg tutorial book
http://http.developer.nvidia.com/CgTutorial/cg_tutorial_chapter09.html
section 9.2.1, glsl version wouldn't be much different from it.

for glsl and only for edges you can do something like

```
 float edge = dot(fragmentNormal, -viewingDirection);
 edge = clamp(edge, 0, 1);
 if(edge < 0.2)
 finalColor = mix(vec3(0, 0, 0), diffuseColor, edge);
```